# jQuery before() adding an element twice

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add an i element to a list with the following jquery code:

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {


// To understand behaviors, see https://drupal.org/node/756722#behaviors
Drupal.behaviors.my_custom_behavior = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {

    $('.menu-mlid-487 a').before('<i class = "icon-overview"></i>');
    $('.menu-mlid-487 a').before('<i class = "icon-admissions"></i>');
    $('.menu-mlid-487 a').before('<i class = "icon-curriculum"></i>');
    $('.menu-mlid-487 a').before('<i class = "icon-faculty"></i>');
    $('.menu-mlid-487 a').before('<i class = "con-testimonial"></i>');
    $('.menu-mlid-487 a').before('<i class = "icon-calendar"></i>');

  }
};

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

However, the result is that the i element is printed twice.

```
<ul class="menu clearfix">
  <li class="first leaf active-trail active menu-mlid-487">
    <i class = "icon-overview"></i>
    <i class = "icon-overview"></i>
    <a href="/emba" title="" class="sf-depth-2 active-trail active">Overview</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I tried using append() but it also prints twice. Is there anything wrong with the code I'm using?

**Update:**

The js file is called through the Drupal theme .info file as below:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/style.css
stylesheets[print][] = css/print.css

scripts[] = js/script.js

regions[header] = Header
regions[navigation] = Navigation
regions[help] = Help
regions[page_top] = Page top
regions[page_bottom] = Page bottom
regions[highlighted] = Highlighted

regions[content] = Content
regions[under_content_wide] = Under Content Wide
regions[sidebar_first] = Sidebar first
regions[sidebar_second] = Sidebar second

regions[triptych_first] = Triptych first
regions[triptych_middle] = Triptych middle
regions[triptych_last] = Triptych last

regions[footer_firstcolumn] = Footer first column
regions[footer_secondcolumn] = Footer second column
regions[footer_thirdcolumn] = Footer third column
regions[footer_fourthcolumn] = Footer fourth column
regions[footer] = Footer
```

The relevant line is the one with scripts[]

Comment: then the given code is executed twice... add a logging statement before the said code and see how many times it is called

Comment: can you please show the whole jQuery code? this line of code has no problem, the problem must lie somewhere else

Comment: Can you post the whole snippet? It looks like the jQuery line is being called twice.

Comment: Well, I am using drupal and that's the extent of the javascript I've written for the entire theme.

Comment: @HuiJingChen Also, you say you're using `.append()`, but `.append()` is clearly not in the above code.  Show us the rest of your code.  It's relevant!

Comment: @Daedalus I said I TRIED using append() but it did not work either. The code I posted uses before().

Comment: @HuiJingChen Where?  I see no usage of `.before()`?

Comment: @Daedalus I apologise, the code I pasted over was different from the original question I posted. I used the addClass() function to resolve the problem with my current implementation, but I still don't understand why using .before() will render the element twice.

Comment: @HuiJingChen Where is the code that calls the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `$('.menu-mlid-487 a')` matches two elements? Then when you `$('.menu-mlid-487 a').addClass("icon-overview");` two elements will have the same class `"icon-overview"`.

use console.log to output `$('.menu-mlid-487 a')`.

And yes, like everyone said, you leave us with speculation and guesses because you don't provide enough information. I think if you looked for enough information to ask your question rightly, you would have found the answer yourself :)